# How to search from SQLite w.r.t a string with single quote and double quotes in Android?

Tags: android, string, sqlite, quotes, double-quotes

I am querying SQLite from Android using cursor in the following way

```
Cursor searchCusor = getCursorForSearchQuery(str);
```

where str is a string. This string may contain single quote and double quotes. So when the cursor tries to search it throws an exception

```
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "' AND latitude != 0 AND longitude != 0 ORDER BY title ASC": , while compiling: SELECT _id, title FROM node WHERE title LIKE '%'%' AND latitude != 0 AND longitude != 0 ORDER BY title ASC
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:53)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1412)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1296)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1251)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1331)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at com.mid.kew.apies.KewDatabaseHelper.getCursorForSearchMapPage(KewDatabaseHelper.java:285)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at com.mid.kew.activities.MapFragment.getCursorForSearchQuery(MapFragment.java:538)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at com.mid.kew.activities.MapFragment.access$12(MapFragment.java:537)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at com.mid.kew.activities.MapFragment$6.afterTextChanged(MapFragment.java:348)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6271)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:6454)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextHasChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:903)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:359)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:275)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:438)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:415)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:583)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:174)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:120)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:247)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:73)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-12 17:32:11.961: E/AndroidRuntime(2337):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried replacing the single quotes as follows

```
str.replace("'", "\' ");
```

But this didn't work out and gave the same error

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown what your `getCursorForSearchQuery` method does, but my guess is that it just includes the value directly in the SQL. Don't do that. Use a parameterized SQL query with `PreparedStatement`, and all should be well. Not only will your current error go away, but you'll also have closed a SQL Injection Attack vulnerability, and you'll be in a better position to handle other data types without conversion issues.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the help... This is what the method do myDatabase.query("node", new String[]{"_id","title"}, "title LIKE \'%" + stringToSearch +"%\' AND latitude != 0 AND longitude != 0" ,null, null,null, "title ASC"); Can you please place an example of what you suggested me please.

Comment: @Raj: See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html and related topics.

Comment: Thank you again... I tried the following line and it worked... myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT _id,title FROM node WHERE title LIKE ? AND latitude != 0 AND longitude != 0 ORDER BY title ASC", new String[]{"%"+stringToSearch+"%"}); is this what you ment in your answer

Comment: @Raj: Well, I'd probably use a SQLiteStatement, but that's at least the *kind* of thing I meant. You still need to think about what happens if the input contains "%" signs, but at least you're not going to get SQL injection attacks...

Answer (score 0):

I previously used the following statement

```
myDatabase.query("node", new String[]{"_id","title"}, "title LIKE \'%" + stringToSearch +"%\' AND latitude != 0 AND longitude != 0" ,null, null,null, "title ASC");
```

which created the issue I mentioned

So I modified the query to

```
myDb.query("node", new String[]{"_id","title"}, "title LIKE ? AND latitude != 0 AND longitude != 0" ,new String[]{"%"+stringToSearch+"%"}, null,null, "title ASC");
```

and it's working fine now.